# Are ethyl iodophenylundecylate and Ethyl-10-(Iodophenylundecanoate) the same compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, drugs, pharmacology

I have no understanding of chemistry, so these to chemical formulas mean nothing to me. What I am trying to ascertain is are these compounds the same? If not, what differences are there especially if injected into the CSF [which they were]?

1. Known as Ethyl Iodophenylundecylate:

   ```
   CH3
   I   (CH2)8 COOC2 H5
   CH
   ```
2. Known as Ethyl-10-(Iodophenylundecanoate)

   ```
   CH3
   I -CH2 (CH2)6 CH2 COOC2 H5
   CH
   ```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input Beginner and Martin, what I am trying to understand is why would this formula be changed 30 years later why would the developers not just leave it as is.

Comment: The formula is still the same. Could you provide your source of information, maybe we can be of better help then. For example, add a picture or a citation.

Answer (score 3):

The "structures" you are trying to post and their respective names do not match, as I cannot spot a phenyl group in there. (Also it is hard to tell from this diagram.) But based on what you gave us, I believe these are the same compounds, where ethyl 10-(4-iodophenyl)undecanoate is the correct IUPAC name and Ethyl iodophenylundecylate is a shortened synonym. I also found trivial names for this compound, for example Pantopaque and Iofendylate.

You can access this molecules record on [ChemSpider](https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.7178.html) and you will find a couple more names attached to it. From the same page is the following structure taken:
[image: ethyl 10-(4-iodophenyl)undecanoate]
<sub>(source: [chemspider.com](https://www.chemspider.com/ImagesHandler.ashx?id=7178&w=200&h=200))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The answer, in principal, is not. But, based on your info, the correct structure is not so easy to determine and the reason is, as Martin states, there is no info related the positions of the functional groups (This is to say the Iodine and the phenyl). However and taken literally the structure name you shared, the structures are:

The structure of the named compound Ethyl 1-( [# ?]-Iodophenyl)-undecylenate is:

[image: First_Compound]

The structure of the named compound Ethyl 10-Iodo-phenyl-undecanoate is:

[image: Second_Compound]

But most probably is Ethyl 10-( [# ?]-Iodophenyl)-undecanoate (Similar as Martin presented):

[image: Second_Compound]

Related to the second part of the question about their activity into CSF is hard to say based on the incomplete info to determine their respective influence. May be is more easy to look at any [vademecum](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=vademecum&oq=vademecum&aqs=chrome..69i57.3688j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=vademecum&tbm=bks) for a more generally medicine.